# Преобразовать из JSON?

Tags: java, gson

Сервер передает клиенту список, который был преобразован в JSON формат:

```
ArrayList<Goods> goodsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
//Заполнение списка
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
Gson gson = new Gson();
String sent = gson.toJson(goodsArrayList);
oos.writeObject(sent);
```

Клиент принимает:

```
ArrayList<Goods> goodsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
String receive = new String();
receive =(String) oin.readObject();
Gson gson = new Gson();
```

Преобразование строки JSON обратно в `ArrayList<Goods>`:

```
goodsArrayList = gson.fromJson(receive,ArrayList<Goods>);
```

Подсвечивает `ArrayList<Goods>`.

Comment: Я написал такооой ответ на Ваш предыдущий вопрос, а потом бац и вопрос удален, эх :( Вы могли бы подключить библиотеку просто прописав одну строчку в Intellij IDEA, ничего вручную не скачивая и не разархивируя.

Comment: ))там все скачал и настроил уже

Comment: В будущем бы пригодилось, но как хотите. А по поводу этого вопроса: когда IDE что-то `Подсвечивает`, то она еще и пишет что-то.

Comment: Пишет Expression expected

Comment: зачем вы object stream'ы используете? вы же уже сериализуете за счет json

Comment: Согласен ни к месту он здесь, была другая задумка. Можно писать просто строку в поток, без всякого object stream

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Необходимо определить свой тип:

```
Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Goods>>(){}.getType();
goodsArrayList = gson.fromJson(receive,type);
```

Подробнее: http://www.javenue.info/post/gson-json-api